# Load CSV to dataframe

Tags: shiny

I have a csv file which I want to copy to dataframe.
The csv file dose not have any unique identifier. But, it do have a unique column names.

The code, I'm using right now is,

```
inFile <- input$target_upload # loads the csv file details into inFile
dataframe <-
read.csv2(
inFile$datapath,
header = input$header,
sep = input$separator,
as.is = TRUE,
rows.names = NULL,
check.names = FALSE
)
```

In the above code, if I use,
row.names = NULL, the column data is shifting towards left .. For eg., Column1 data is shifting to row.names and so on, which leads to last column as empty.
row.names = 1, 'I'm getthing duplicate row.names error' (I do agree for this error, because, !st column has duplicate data...in fact all the columns have duplicate data)

I just want to copy data from CSV to dataframe as is. How can acheive it?

My CSV is in the following format :

COL1; COL2; COL3; COL4

abc;1234;test; test1

cde;1234;test2;test3

abc;5678;test;test1

Comment: You already received answers [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/problem-while-reading-csv-file/180390/8).